# Connect to selenium inside docker container

Tags: docker, laradock

I trying connect to selenium, but I getting error:

Failed to connect to localhost port 4444: Connection refused

What is wrong? It is works normally in browser: http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/ and I see selenium.

I also tried connect to different port (eg. elastic) and it is these same.

Answer (score 0):

You havent provided anough info on how your `Dockerfile` looks like and what command you're running to start the container. Please do that.

In any case here are some important points.

First in your dockerfile I hope you have

```
EXPOSE 4444
```

Secondly, if you just deploy your container using the `docker run` command, it will not be available to your localhost UNLESS you expose the required ports. Run your container with the below command :

```
docker run -p 4444:4444 -itd <IMAGE-ID>
```

Also make sure that the firewalld/iptables services on your machine are correctly configured to allow access to `4444`

Comment: I used Laradock,your command return: docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint hopeful_goodall (0b6b5615c157b4275bb128c777da91de519451141cfca28c6aee00eb6e559b8f): Bind for 0.0.0.0:4444 failed: port is already allocated.

I works from browser (http://localhost:4444/), put when I try connect from php code inside docker, its return error: Failed to connect to localhost port 4444: Connection refused